# Grouping Rectangle element in a list based on their Y value

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to group text regions which represents with Rectangle based upon their Y value of bottom side and I write the GroupSentces function and got infinite loop. Please help me to fix the function. GroupSentence function is to group the text region to represent a sentence.

```
public void GroupSentences()
        {
            groupedsentences = new List<List<Rectangle>>();
            List<Rectangle> copysentences = sentences.ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < sentences.Count; i++)
            {
                List<Rectangle> recs = new List<Rectangle>();
                Rectangle rec = sentences.ElementAt(i);
                recs.Add(rec);
                copysentences.Remove(rec) ;
                List<int> foundedindex = new List<int>();
                List<Rectangle> foundedrecs = new List<Rectangle>();

                for (int j = 0; j < copysentences.Count; j++)
                {
                    Rectangle nextrec = copysentences.ElementAt(j);
                    if (Math.Abs(rec.Bottom - nextrec.Bottom) <= 2 ||
                        Math.Abs(nextrec.Bottom - rec.Bottom) <= 2)
                    {
                        foundedindex.Add(j);
                        Rectangle foundedrec = copysentences.ElementAt(j);
                        foundedrecs.Add(foundedrec);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var item in foundedrecs)
                {
                    copysentences.Remove(item);
                }
                foreach (var item in foundedindex)
                {
                    recs.Add(copysentences.ElementAt(item));
                }
                groupedsentences.Add(recs);


                if (sentences.Count > 0)
                {
                    i = -1;
                }
                else
                    return;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please include the code as *text* rather than as an image - and ideally provide a [mcve]. The easier it is for us to reproduce the problem, the quicker you're likely to get a solution.

Comment: Images of code attract downvotes.  Post the text version instead.  We need to know the platform too: WinForms, WPF, etc.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: So the question is about an infinite loop, not about the things you actually want to achieve, which is totally unclear to me. But: The by far best way to solve such issues is using the debugger! Break into it while it runs and see where it is stuck and how large the lists are etc...

Comment: My application is Windows form application. Please help.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't set the running index to -1, but this is just a guess..

Comment: `  i = -1;` this will cause the infinite loop

Comment: A suggestion, use comments in your code so we can understand it. You may know what your code is doing but we **don't**.

Answer (score 0):

Here a good example, First I Sort the copied list with a binary sort (faster than comparing 2 elements in 2 loops). Next I loop once through the list and create a new group when the previous item is smaller than the next. Enjoy!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ee
{
    public class Core
    {

        public static void Main()
        {
            GroupSorter gs = new GroupSorter();
            gs.GroupCorrect();

        }

    }


    public class GroupSorter
    {
        List<Rectangle> sentences = new List<Rectangle>();
        List<List<Rectangle>> groupedsentences = new List<List<Rectangle>>();

        public GroupSorter()
        {
            Random recBottom = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                sentences.Add(new Rectangle() { Bottom = recBottom.Next(10) });
            }
        }

        public void GroupCorrect()
        {
            List<Rectangle> copysentences = new List<Rectangle>(sentences);
            copysentences.Sort();

            List<Rectangle> lastGroup = null;
            bool createGroup = true;

            foreach (Rectangle r in copysentences)
            {
                if (lastGroup != null)
                {
                    Rectangle compRec = lastGroup[0]; //Get last group, first element
                    createGroup = (compRec.CompareTo(r) != 0); //BottomRec not equal so new group
                }

                if (createGroup)
                {
                    lastGroup = new List<Rectangle>();
                    groupedsentences.Add(lastGroup);
                }
                lastGroup.Add(r);

            }

        }


    }

    public class Rectangle: IComparable<Rectangle>
    {
        public Rectangle()
        { }
        public int Bottom { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Rectangle other)
        {
            return Bottom.CompareTo(other.Bottom);
        }
    }
}
```